# For Loop with Logical Condition in R

Tags: r, for-loop, logical-operators

I am trying to create a test/training data set. The criteria for the data set is that there must be a max of 15 records from each user. So if a user has > 15 records I only want to take 15 records.

My for loop is stuck in an infinity loop.

testid=NULL

for(a in unique(oobData$`user id`)){

```
if(max(oobData$surgeon_case_count[oobData$`user id`==a])>=15){
testid=c(testid,sample(which(oobData$`user id`==a),size=15))}
else{
testid=c(testid,sample(which(oobData$`user id`==a),size=max(oobData$surgeon_case_count[oobData$`user id` ==a])))
}
```

}

Any ideas?

Comment: It will be much easier if you use `split()` to divide your data by `user id`. Then use `lapply()` to draw samples from each `user id`. You'll need to create a small function that checks the number of rows for each user and then samples 15 or fewer from each user. Your approach requires searching the entire data base for each `user id`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning split I was able to utilize split with a for loop probably similar to lapply and sample to archive desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop for this. Here's one example of a data.table solution.

```
library("data.table")

DT <- data.table(
  id = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 30, replace = TRUE),
  value = sample(seq_len(10), 30, replace = TRUE)
)

DT[, .SD[sample(.N, fifelse(.N > 15, 15, .N))], by = id]
```